# HttpURLConnection getInputStream() not reading anything

Tags: android, http

I'm following an example of using the Reddit API in an Android app. I'm using Android Studio and Java. I have a link which returns a JSON object on a GET request (let's say http://www.reddit.com/r/dragonforce/.json), and the tutorial has this piece of code:

```
public static HttpURLConnection getConnection(String url){
    System.out.println("URL: "+url);
    HttpURLConnection hcon = null;
    try {
        hcon=(HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        hcon.setReadTimeout(30000); // Timeout at 30 seconds
        hcon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Alien V1.0");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("getConnection()",
                "Invalid URL: "+e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("getConnection()",
                "Could not connect: "+e.toString());
    }

    return hcon;
}
```

and

```
public static String readContents(String url){
    HttpURLConnection hcon=getConnection(url);
    if(hcon==null) return null;

    try{
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(8192);
        String tmp="";
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        hcon.getInputStream()
                )
        );
        tmp = br.readLine();
        while(tmp !=null) {
            sb.append(tmp).append("\n");
            tmp = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.d("READ FAILED", e.toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

I separated the tmp assignment for debug purposes. The problem is that nothing is read from the inputStream, and it returns an empty buffer to the JSONObject parser, resulting in `JSONException  end of input at character 0 of`. I have user-permission in the Manifest for INTERNET, and the syntax for reading from the URL seems to be backed up by other sources on the internet, but it still seems something is amiss. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is reading this down the line, the problem was that the URL in the tutorial was using HTTP instead of HTTPS, leading to a redirect response code and wasn't returning anything.